# Laravel - sql query with session

Tags: php, sql, laravel, session

I would like to display the table based on SESSION USERNAME and using the following query but I am getting error.

```
SELECT tb_list.* FROM tb_list  
WHERE username = ".Session::get('username')."
```

**Error: Class 'App\Models\Session' not found**

Could you please help me

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Session class like:

```
use Session;
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Comment: Ye the second one worked. Thank you very much. But it works only when it is WHERE id = ".Session::get('uid')." How can I make it work with WHERE username = ".Session::get('username')."

Comment: For logged in user, You can try this one 
WHERE username = Auth::user()->username